# Is it okay to use 3 ports for just one application?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack, uploadcare

I'm building a MEAN stack app. And here's the structure:

- A MongoDB database is on one port
- The images are hosted on Uploadcare, and the cdn_url for images are in the MongoDB database
- The application is going to have its own URL, like "gofloppy.com"

My problem isn't that I can't figure something out, it's that I'm confused if it's okay to use so many urls just for one application. So, is it okay to do something like that or will it end up causing problems down the road?

Comment: What about using 3 ports makes you un-easy?

Comment: Yes, it's OK. Ports exist for that reason: make programs communicate with each other.

Comment: You’re using ports in one place and URLs in another. They’re very different things. But in any case, you have several components, naturally they will have their own connection points.

Comment: you can use as many ports as you want however on one machine URL like "gofloppy.com" will only use PORT 80 by default, for other PORTs you've to access like "gofloppy.com:8081" and so on, no other problem with this

Comment: Okay, I got it thanks!